# Convert PDF with columns to text in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, rubygems

I'm trying to extract text from a dictionary pdf where the layout have 2 columns like this [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqUww.png)(srry, i have the pdf file, not the url)
and I tried to use pdf-reader gem but the text it's a mess because instead it follows the column text flow, it just ignores and keep reading the line like:

```
io = open("#{Rails.root.join("public", "dictionary.pdf")}")
@reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
@reader.page(23).text
```

This print something like:

> A B C D E A F G H I J K a critério. vide CRITÉRIO.abandono de emprego.
> (dir. do trabalho) vo- L luntary quit; constructive voluntary quit
> [Co- a descoberto. vide SACAR; SAQUE (a descoberto). M vington, Robert
> N. Employment Law, p. 361]. à mão armada. vide ASSALTO. N abandono de
> lar. desertion.

I could try to extract the text page by page but have too many pages lol. I try to convert the pdf into html by a random site and didn't seen a lot more easy to extract the text soo.. I already see some tutorials to user receiver but didn't looks like it's gonna work too. Oh, and srry for my bad english lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parsing PDF file is difficult](https://gist.github.com/amitpatelx/a317e9712ffeb527df1795cd68546956).

Few years back I researched all available options to parse PDF to extract text and I end up with [pdftotext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext#:%7E:text=pdftotext%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,of%20the%20Xpdf%20Windows%20port.). I haven't seen any other library having accuracy the **pdftotext** gives.

You can use this utility and call it using ruby's `system` command to execute shell command `pdftotext`

Comment: I tried install the gem pdftotext but still no sucess. Even when I use layout option

Comment: `pdftotext` is unix utility. Check out https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/converter-pdf-files-to-text-format-command/